# How exactly does Angelina design games?

Tags: game-ai, reference-request

In the recent [festival of science](https://live.newscientist.com/), there was a talk given by researcher [Mike Cook](https://live.newscientist.com/mike-cook/) about:

> [ANGELINA](http://www.gamesbyangelina.org/), an AI game designer that has invented game mechanics, made games about news stories, and was the first AI to enter a game jam.

So the aim of Angelina AI is basically to design videogames.

Briefly, how exactly does Angelina design the new games? How does it work behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, it appears that much of his past work on Github involves *procedural generation*. Which is AI... ish. Unless there's more to it, which we can't see because half the site is down.

[This paper](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ecdrage/papers/SOCS-TR-2011.1.pdf) appears to offer an analysis of combining procedural generation with game AI.

From the abstract:

> Populated and immersive game contexts require large numbers of minor,
> background characters to fill out the virtual environment. To limit
> game AI development effort, however, such characters are typically
> represented by very simplistic AI with either little difference
> between characters or only highly formulaic variations. Here we
> describe a complete workflow and framework for easily designing,
> generating and incorporating multiple, interesting game AIs. Our
> approach uses high-level, visual Statechart models to represent
> behaviour in a modular form; this allows for not only simplistic,
> parameterbased variation in AI design, but also permits more complex
> structure-based approaches. We demonstrate our technique by applying
> it to the task of generating a large number of individual AIs for
> computer-controlled squirrels within the Mammoth [1](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ecdrage/papers/SOCS-TR-2011.1.pdf) framework for
> game research. Rapid development and easy deployment of AIs allow us
> to create a wide variety of interesting AIs, greatly improving the
> sense of immersion in a virtual environment.

[Here's an article](http://newatlas.com/creative-ai-procedural-game-development-angelina/35874/) from 2015 on AI and procedural generation, which discusses Angelina at length. This article links to [a more in-depth article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2013-04-02-plastic-soul-one-mans-quest-to-build-an-ai-that-can-create-games) from 2013.

Here's an excerpt:

> Cook gave ANGELINA the ability to learn about people so that it could
> make games based on current events. Then Cook gave ANGELINA memory -
> that is, the ability to keep track of the people it had learned about.
> The memory's not a big deal, even though it led to a number of
> philosophical disagreements around Cook's desk. ANGELINA's memory is
> actually just a text file where it stores the names of all the people
> it's heard of, alongside a number: a measure of its opinion of them
> based on the things it's learned from internet chatter. It liked
> Al-Assad more than May. It liked everyone more than May.